# Events Won't Display for Codecademy's Calendar AngularJS Homework Assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

[Codecademy's Calendar Assignment](http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/4/calendar/README.html)

[Github](https://github.com/b3ckm4n/calendar-angularjs)

This is my first question on Stack so I'm not sure the best way to showcase the assignment and code, so I'm going to link to them for now.

I'm trying to get events to display based on the assignment above but can't figure out what is wrong for the life of me.

I built the service and modified the controller and view pages to the point where I believe they should display the events in the view, but I'm just seeing one unreplaced expression.

I feel like I am probably not retrieving the data properly and accessing it in the view/html.

Any ideas?

### Index.html

```
<body ng-app="CalendarApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <img src= "img/logo.svg" width="51" height="54">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">

        <div ng-view></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/DayController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/events.js"></script>

  </body>
```

---

### views/day.html

```
<h2 class="date">{{ day.date | date }}</h2>

<div class="event" ng-repeat="event in events">
  <a href="#/{{$index}}">
    <h3 class="name">{{ day.event.name }}</h3>
    <p><span class="from">{{ day.event.from }}</span> - <span class="to">{{ day.event.to }}</span></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

### js/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('CalendarApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        controller: 'DayController',
        templateUrl: 'views/day.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

---

### js/controllers/DayController

```
app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, $events) {
    events.success(function(data) {
        $scope.day = data;
    });  
}]);
```

---

### js/services/events.js

```
app.factory('events', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
}]);
```

Comment: You need to share your code here, the minimum code that reproduce your issue

Comment: Got it, updated. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hey, did you get this fixed? I have the exact same problem. Any angularness expression on the view is not being evaluated, I don't know why.

Comment: Ok I solved my problem. I forgot to return the http.get result in the factory :). That caused angularjs to fail and evaluate the expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code-block, you named events $events when passing it to the function.

```
//app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, $events) {
app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, events) {
    events.success(function(data) {
        $scope.day = data;
    });  
}]);
```

That is the only error I could find on replicating the project assuming your actual project had angular and angular-routes being correctly pulled into your project (They were missing from your index.html).

EDIT: To display the events in the view, you need to set up your ng-repeat differently.  Currently, you have "day" in front of the wrong variable.  Swap it and it should work as expected.  ($scope.events is undefined but $scope.day.events is the list you are looking for in the ng-repeat.  Once inside the ng-repeat, the individual elements of the array $scope.day.events are referenced as $scope.event)

```
<h2 class="date">{{ day.date | date }}</h2>

<div class="event" ng-repeat="event in day.events">
  <a href="#/{{$index}}">
    <h3 class="name">{{ event.name }}</h3>
    <p><span class="from">{{ event.from }}</span> - <span class="to">{{ event.to }}</span></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks for pointing that out! I noticed the debug message but wasn't sure what it meant. 

However, when I make the change, I see the date appear but nothing else. I think it might have to do with how I'm calling the event in the expression under ng-repeat. I tried swapping the "event" and "day" to no avail (which is probably obvious for some reason that is evading me). Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for controller errors and didn't look into the day.html.  Ng-repeats work differently than you are trying to use them.  I posted the corrected day.html above in the edit.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense! Interestingly, the view is still not showing the events for me. I'm using Cloud9's IDE, so I'll check again later to see if changes needed time to take effect.